# ASP.NET and Neo4jClient - where to store the connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, neo4j, neo4jclient

The C# Neo4JClient has `GraphClient` where you have to call `.Connect()`

```
var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
client.Connect();
```

In all of the examples that I've seen, it's in a Console app, so they declare `GraphClient` in `Main()` and re-use it. And the documentation mentions how its Thread Safe and to only have one instance per database and to not call `.Connect()` multiple times.

But what about in ASP.NET applications? Should I be sticking it in some static class that is accessed by the pages (or store it in the Application state)? Like this:

```
public class DbConnection
{
    private static GraphClient _client;
    public static GraphClient GraphClient
    {
        get
        {
            if (_client == null)
            {
                _client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
                _client.Connect();
            }
            return _client;
        }
    }
}
```

And then in any ASPX page I could simply:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GraphClient client = DbConnection.GraphClient;
    //do whatever I need to with client
}
```

Or am I not understanding that correctly, and that would cause all kinds of problems? Do I need to call `.Connect()` in each method (or maybe once per page lifecycle), like so:

```
private GraphClient _client;
private GraphClient PageGraphClient
{
    get { //same as in previous, check if null and load _client with the connection }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do whatever I need to with PageGraphClient
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do whatever I need to with PageGraphClient
}
```

And so on? I guess I'm just getting hung up on the whole Thread Safe thing and "making too many connections to the db" and wanting to make sure I'm not missing an easy/correct way to do this.

(and yes, I know that I shouldn't be calling the database commands from the ASPX pages directly, I'm over-simplifying for the sake of understanding how the GraphClient class works ;)

Comment: What are your feelings towards dependency injection? Have you done it before - are you comfortable using it?

Comment: @chris-skardon I've not had to do it before, but I'm open to learning something new if it's the right approach?

Comment: OK - Is this an ASP.NET aspx project, or an MVC project?

Comment: @ChrisSkardon it's an MVC project.

Comment: Reply from 2018: the official driver page still not explaining this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set up your project with Ninject (DI framework):

- Add the Ninject.MVC nuget package for your MVC version (i.e. Ninject.MVC5 etc)
- Add the Neo4jClient package (though I imagine you already have this)
- Hook up Ninject so it knows what an `IGraphClient` is

I use a Module for this, so add this class to your project (usually I have them in a sub-folder called ‘Modules’ in the App_Start folder – but it can be anywhere):

```
public class Neo4jModule : NinjectModule
{
    /// <summary>Loads the module into the kernel.</summary>
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IGraphClient>().ToMethod(InitNeo4JClient).InSingletonScope();
    }

    private static IGraphClient InitNeo4JClient(IContext context)
    {
        var neo4JUri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Neo4j"].ConnectionString);
        var graphClient = new GraphClient(neo4JUri);
        graphClient.Connect();

        return graphClient;
    }
}
```

We've loaded the GraphClient in a singleton scope which you can read all about here: [Object Scopes](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes)

Now we just need to tell Ninject to load the module, so in the `NinjectWebCommon.cs` file (in the App_Start folder) edit the `RegisterServices` method (at the bottom of the file) so it looks like:

```
/// <summary>
/// Load your modules or register your services here!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Load<Neo4jModule>();
}
```

- Inject into the controller

Which is a case of adding a constructor (or modifying an existing one) to take an `IGraphClient` instance:

```
private readonly IGraphClient _graphClient;
public HomeController(IGraphClient graphClient)
{
    _graphClient = graphClient;
}
```

Now the controller has an instance of the `GraphClient` to use as and when it pleases:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.NodeCount =  _graphClient.Cypher.Match("n").Return(n => n.Count()).Results.Single();

    return View();
}
```

Obviously extending this, you could add a base `Neo4jController` which any controllers requiring Neo4j override.

Comment: okay, cool, makes a lot of sense, thanks! I'll read up on all of this, but the one question I have left is more just for my own education, and that is: is this keeping the Neo4jClient connection open for the life of the Application, or per-request to the Controller action, or how is that working? I'm just curious.

Comment: The link to 'Object Scopes' will help you there, but there are four options, Transient - New instance created each time you request it, Singleton - Only single instance is created and returned for every request, Thread - One instance per thread, Request - one instance per web request, destroyed when the request ends.

Comment: right, that I get, sorry, I probably didn't ask it correctly, I was wondering more, what's the best practice for the Neo4jClient in terms of keeping one connection open or if it should be constantly opening and closing connections with each request. I don't see any kind of connection pooling options like the MongoDB C# driver handles for you, so I'm just trying to understand if that's something I'll need to build on top of that.