# Neo4j single instance of connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, neo4j, ninject, neo4jclient

I'am working at application in ASP.NET MVC 5 which is supported by Neo4j graph database. I'am using Neo4jClient and Neo4j.AspNet.Identity. To connect with database there is a class called `GraphClient`. Below is the way to instatiate connection:

```cs
var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
    client.Connect();
```

As far as i know GraphClient is thread safe. It's required have one instance of it. Following this topic [ASP.NET and Neo4jClient - where to store the connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703154/asp-net-and-neo4jclient-where-to-store-the-connection) I've used Ninject for resolve this problem. That's the code:

```cs
public class Neo4jClient:NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IGraphClient>().ToMethod(InitializeNeo4jClient).InSingletonScope();
    }
    private static IGraphClient InitializeNeo4jClient(IContext context )
    {
        var graphClient = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
        graphClient.Connect();
        return graphClient;
    }
}
```

Code in `NinjectWebCommon.cs`

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
   kernel.Load<Neo4jClient>();
}
```

Everything seems to be fine but i have a problem with `Neo4j.AspNet.Identity`
In class `Startup.Auth.cs`there is this code

```
public partial class Startup
    {

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
            ConfigureNeo4j(app);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);


            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {

                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });            
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);


            app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));


            app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);


        }
        private void ConfigureNeo4j(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => {
                var gc = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost.:7474/db/data"));
                gc.Connect();
                var gcw = new GraphClientWrapper(gc);
                return gcw;
            });
        }
    }
```

As You Can See in `ConfigureNeo4j(IAppBuilder app)` method there is an another instance of GraphClient to pass the context. My question is how can i pass the GraphClient instance from Ninject to this method? How to resolve problem with multiple instance of GraphClient in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's a couple of things you'll need to do around this, first - as you can see - you use `OWIN` for the Identity and `Ninject` for the rest of the site, the easiest approach is to make `OWIN` know about the `Ninject Kernel`, aaaand the `Ninject Kernel` to know about the `GraphClientWrapper`.

#### 1. Add a binding for `GraphClientWrapper` to `Ninject`

Add the following to your `NinjectModule`:

```
private GraphClientWrapper(IContext arg) { 
    return new GraphClientWrapper(Kernel.Get<IGraphClient>()); 
}
```

Add this to the module `Load` method:

```
Kernel.Bind<GraphClientWrapper>().ToMethod(GetGraphClientWrapper).InSingletonScope();
```

**NB** You do need to have the `Kernel.Bind<IGraphClient>()` *before* this (for obvious reasons).

#### 2. Update `NinjectWebCommon` to have an `internal` `Kernel` property

Add:

```
internal static IKernel Kernel { get; private set; }
```

and then in the `CreateKernel` method add:

```
Kernel = kernel;
```

just before you `return kernel;`

#### 3. Bind `OWIN` to the `Ninject Kernel`

Finally, change the `ConfigureNeo4j` method to be:

```
private void ConfigureNeo4j(IAppBuilder app) {
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => NinjectWebCommon.Kernel.Get<GraphClientWrapper>());
}
```

One instance for all!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the solution !